# Google map are blank after published on market

Tags: android, google-maps

in my application i'm using google maps api v2 .in debug mode my map is working perfect on my device but when i published it to the market and i install it from the market i see a blank map like a gray screen . i know it's something about the API key it's not the first time i publishing application with google map but "google developer console" change they site and i can't remember how to fix it and make its works . please help me!!i tried everything what can i do ?

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API KEY" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="4323000" />
```

[image]

Comment: In your developer console, open your project and go to **APIs & Auth** > **Credentials**. Create or edit **Public Key**, add *SHA1 fingerprint* from your production keystore, that corresponding to this `API KEY` from your manifest file.

Comment: I've done that in the beginning.. i got the api_key and my map working good , but after i publish it to the market the map are blank

Comment: Remember that your debug keystore is not the same as your release keystore, you must have one api_key for each one

Answer (score 2):

In your developer console,

APIS & auth > Credentials > Public API Access (Key For Android Applications) > Android Applications

You should have 2 SHA1 fingerprint certificates there, one for your debug, and release.

Do you have one for release?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: No i see only: "API KEY" and "Obsolete key"

Comment: you should have two keys.  You add both keys manually.  They are separated by (CIW) a ;

Comment: CIW ? what is this . and how i handle with "keytool -list -keystore your_keystore_name" what is that line ?

Comment: From your screen shot, you only have one Android Applications SHA1 fingerprint. Normally, you would have 2 (from your debug keytore and release keystore). So which fingerprint is that? I would think that's your Debug fingerprint. You need to add your release fingerprint there. Follow the instructions on the link I specified. Then click "Edit Allowed Android applications", then paste your release signature.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there are two keys.

Debug key and release key.

You are using debug key and publishing which ofcourse gives you blank screen. Use release key to    support in your app.

For release key steps are here

```
Step 1:
```

Say for example your apk name is A and you are signing and creating a keystore for A.apk ie A.keystore will be created in some drive location.Let's consider it in E drive.

step 2:

Now locate to jdk in C drive(Considering for windows and assigning C drive)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore E:\A.keystore -alias A

So it will create SHA-1 fingure print

copy and paste that in google map console, it wll generate a key.use it in maps.

For shortcut to get SHA1 is :) export your apk-> sign all things -> there you can find SHA1 finger print. use that in Google console and generate. Then use that key in manifest file